# My canvas app is not working, please help (java script)

Tags: javascript

I followed a tutorial on javascript to make a canvas app but its not working, I followed every step.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'

function draw(x, y){
    const circle = new Path2D();
    circle.arc(x, y, 10 ,0, 2 + Math.PI);
    ctx.fill(circle)
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) --> {
    const {
        clientX,
        clientY
    } = e
    ,draw(clientX - rect.left, clientY - rect.top)
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) --> {
    console.log('mouseup')
})'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code fixed.

Firstly, you used `() -->`, instead of `() =>`.
Secondly, you did:

```js
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = e,
  draw(clientX - rect.left, clientY - rect.top);
```

Instead of:

```js
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = e;
  draw(clientX - rect.left, clientY - rect.top);
```

The difference is the `,` was swapped for a `;`.
That is because `,` would be assigning and destructure the `draw()` section to `{ clientX, clientY }`. By replacing it with `;`, I am ending the assignment.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'

function draw(x, y) {
  const circle = new Path2D();
  circle.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 + Math.PI);
  ctx.fill(circle)
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  const {
    clientX,
    clientY
  } = e;
  draw(clientX - rect.left, clientY - rect.top);
})
```

```css
#draw {
  border: 2px black dashed;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="draw" />
```

I would recommend using a library designed for this, such as [p5.js](https://p5js.org/)

Comment: You may want to re-look at your snippet. You provided a non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of problems here:

Your function syntax is wrong it should use an equals sign `=>` not `-->`

If you want a full circle use `2 * Math.PI` You are using `2 + Math.PI`

`rect` is not defined anywhere. Most likely it is supposed to be `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()`

For your mouse function just use

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  draw(e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top)
})
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'

function draw(x, y){
    const circle = new Path2D();
    circle.arc(x, y, 10 ,0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill(circle)
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  draw(e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top)
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {

})
```

```html
<canvas id="draw"></canvas>
```